# populate values in textbox if select combobox vb6

Tags: vb6

I am using VB 6.0 I have one form (Form1), 1 combobox (ComboBox1), and 1 textbox (TextBox1)I have one table (Salary) in my local database which was created within the project.In Table 'Salary' I only have Four columns (UserID - Primary Key, Salary Type, Salary Range)the table has multiple records in it.

What I need to find out is how do have get the textbox to populate with the corresponding columns for whatever is selected in the combobox. Any and all help would be appreciated.

Here is the code which i was used to link database with VB :

```
Private WithEvents cmdPopulate As CommandButton
Private WithEvents dcbDataCombo As DataCombo

Private Sub Form_Load()

    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strConnect As String
    Dim strSQL   As String

    strConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Mahmoud\Desktop\Project\Database.mdb;Persist Security Info=False"
    strSQL = "Select Distinct * FROM Salary order by UserID asc"  ' set ascending order

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    With rs
       .CursorType = adOpenStatic
       .LockType = adLockReadOnly
       .Open Source:=strSQL, _
          ActiveConnection:=strConnect, _
          Options:=adCmdText
    End With

    Set DataCombo1.RowSource = rs
    DataCombo1.ListField = "UserID"
    DataCombo1.DataField = "UserID"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my answer from just the click event to a complete example:

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents cmdPopulate As CommandButton
Private WithEvents dcbDataCombo As DataCombo
Private rs As ADODB.Recordset

Private Sub Form_Load()
   Dim strConnect As String
   Dim strSQL As String
   Dim cn As ADODB.Connection

   strConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Mahmoud\Desktop\Project\Database.mdb;Persist Security Info=False"
   strSQL = "Select Distinct * FROM Salary order by UserID asc"  ' set ascending order

   Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
   cn.ConnectionString = strConnect
   cn.Open
   cn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
   Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
   rs.Open strSQL, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

   Set DataCombo1.RowSource = rs
   DataCombo1.ListField = "UserID"
   DataCombo1.DataField = "UserID"
End Sub

Private Sub DataCombo1_Click(Area As Integer)
   rs.MoveFirst
   rs.Find "UserID = " & DataCombo1.Text
   If Not (rs.BOF Or rs.EOF) Then TextBox1.Text = rs.Fields("SalaryType").Value
End Sub
```

If the field name `SalaryType` is not correct then fix as needed.

Comment: No you did not understand me well as example i want to populate salary type in textbox where userid is matched with combobox selection

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

```
ActiveConnection:=strConnect
```

but strConnect is a string, while ActiveConnection require a ADODB.Connection object, not a string. Moreover, the connection must be already Open:

```
Dim CN As ADODB.Connection
Set CN = New ADODB.Connection
CN.ConnectionString = strConnect
CN.Open
CN.CursorLocation = adUseClient

' for recordset:
rs.Open strSQL, CN, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
```

Comment: Thanks Giorgio , I am beginner on this area so if you can help me in which line should the code be added and what the line should be amended as i need the results to be appear in text box after combobox selection